# Перехват изменения свойств структуры

Tags: php

Добрый день! Уважаемые знатоки, пожалуйста подскажите - есть ли возможность перехватить изменение поведения, уже ранее определенных свойств?

```
final class a {
    public $name = 'default';
}
$a = new a;
$a->name = 1;
echo $a->name; // 1
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы это свойство нельзя было изменять динамически, но при этом, чтобы оно было публичное.
Динамические добавления отследить удалось, а вот уже ранее созданные не могу понять как перехватит.

Comment: const NAME = 'default'  - вам такой вариант не подходит ?

Comment: исключено. только свойства

Comment: опечатка: поведение->значение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать [магию](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get).

```
final class A {
    private $_name = 'default';

    public function __get( $name ){
        if( $name === 'name' ) 
            return $this->_name;
    }

    public function __set( $name, $value ){
        if( $name === 'name' ){
            echo "попытка установить значение для '$name' - игнорим\n" ;
        }
    }
}

$a = new A;
$a->name = 1; // сообщение об игноре
echo $a->name; // default
```

Comment: Сначала пробовал так не работало, а теперь заработало, странно! Проблема решена! Этот вариант рабочий!

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью магических методов __get и __set

```
final class a {
    private $_name = 'default';
    function __set($property, $value) {
     if ($property == 'name'){
        throw new Exception("You can't set value of propert");
     }
     $this->property = $value;
    }

    function __get($property)
    {
       if($property == 'name'){
          return $this->_name;
       }
    }
}
```

Можно в принципе делать полные аналоги свойств https://habrahabr.ru/post/186420/ , во фреймфорках часто так делают через внутренний "массив свойств"